# Initialization and naming, ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, initialization

I have several objects I want to store in an arrayList that represents a single assembly language instruction (eg Add, Jump, etc). The objects in each ArrayList are constant for a given instruction, so I just need to load each of the objects for a given instruction into the proper arrayList once at load time.

The tedious part is that I need to name each of the objects before they're added to the arrayList:

```
    static {
        ...
            ArrayList<CodeFrag[]> intIntGtrEqlProtoCode = new ArrayList<CodeFrag[]>();
...
                        intIntGtrEqlProtoCode.add(intIntGtrEqlInst1);
                        CodeFrag[] intIntGtrEqlInst2 = {Subtract};
                        intIntGtrEqlProtoCode.add(intIntGtrEqlInst2);
                        CodeFrag[] intIntGtrEqlInst3 = {Duplicate};
        ...
    }
```

I have a feeling like there is a way to avoid doing all this extremely tedious naming. Can someone point it out to me?

Comment: `intIntGtrEqlProtoCode.add(new CodeFrag[]{Subtract})`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
CodeFrag[] arr = {Subtract, Duplicate, Foo, Bar};
for (CodeFrag c : arr)
    intIntGtrEqlProtoCode.add(new CodeFrag[]{c});
```

Also, if all of the arrays have length `1`, couldn't you replace it with a `List<CodeFrag>`? Then you could just do

```
intIntGtrEqlProtoCode = new ArrayList<CodeFrag>(Arrays.asList(Subtract, Duplicate, Foo, Bar));
```